# Fading in a canvas object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-animate

For an assignment I need to animate something simple using CSS and JavaScript. I've been able to figure out the CSS but everything I read to make an object fade in using JavaScript just doesn't seem to work with the object I drew in JavaScript. I just wanted to draw a circle in JavaScript and then animate it to fade in in 5 seconds.
Here is the basic Code I have so far:

```
    HTML:

   <body onload="draw();">
        <canvas id="circle" width="450" height="450"></canvas>
    </body>

    JavaScript:

    <script>
        function draw()
        {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('circle');
            if (canvas.getContext)
            {
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
                var X = canvas.width / 2;
                var Y = canvas.height / 2;
                var R = 45;
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(X, Y, R, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                ctx.lineWidth = 3;
                ctx.strokeStyle = '#645862';
                ctx.stroke();
            }
                    
        }
    </script>
```

As you can see I only have the circle part of the code. I have tried multiple versions of different fade in animations but I just can't quite get them to work. I'm not very good at JavaScript. It's the one language I have trouble understanding for some reason. I'm also really sick right now otherwise I would be troubleshooting more reasons as to why it isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

To understand how a canvas works, you need to know that it's just a place to display something, and initially it doesn't do anything on its own. You've drawn the circle once, which is enough to display the circle, but not to animate it in any way.

If we want to move the circle in any direction, we must clear the canvas of the already drawn circle and draw the circle in a different place, changing its coordinates by N pixels. The same goes for transparency. We must change the transparency of the color of the circle in each frame, and draw the circle again and again.

This is how 2D and 3D canvas works, as well as all video games - they draw scenes 60 times per second, changing some values along the way, such as coordinates, values, color, transparency, height and width.

In order for this to work, we need two additional variables, opacity and the direction (fading) in which the opacity changes, to know whether the circle appears or disappears.

Also important is the recursive call to our draw() function. We will call it constantly, and we will constantly redraw our image on the canvas.

I also want to point out some conceptual mistakes in your code.

1. Dont use "var", it is deprecated. Use "let","const". Also don`t repeat "var","var","var" in every line. Use commas.
2. Dont use onload,onclick and others HTML on-attributes. They are only suitable for educational purposes, not for real work. Use script tag and document event listeners.
3. Dont name canvas id like "circle","box" etc. It is not a circle and a box, it is a canvas.
4. Use document.querySelector instead of document.getElementById. It is more modern

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Canvas opacity animation</title>
</head>
<body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="450" height="450"></canvas>
    
    <script>

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{
    const OPACITY_SPEED = .005
    let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        opacity = 1,
        fading = true

        draw()

        function draw(){
                // clear canvas for redrawing (important!)
                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            let circleX = canvas.width/2,
                circleY = canvas.height/2,
                radius = 45

                // changing circle opacity
                if(fading) opacity -= OPACITY_SPEED
                    else opacity += OPACITY_SPEED

                // check if we need to fade in or to fade out
                if(opacity >= 1) fading = true
                if(opacity <= 0) fading = false

                // draw circle
                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(circleX, circleY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                context.lineWidth = 3;
                context.strokeStyle = `rgba(0, 0, 0, ${opacity})`;
                context.stroke();

                // call draw() again and again
                requestAnimationFrame(draw)
        }
})
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the helpful advice! I'm still new to JavaScript and your post has helped me understand it much more than any of the readings I've had to use for this project. I will definitely look over the code and implement it into my website and republish it. I learned more about the canvas attribute and animation with JavaScript from strangers than I have from the readings that are assigned to me in my class.